# How to control the family-wise error rate testing simultaneous hypothesis in two-way Anova?

Tags: anova, post-hoc, two-way, familywise-error

I guess explaining with an example would be best. Let's say we are researching which type of fertilizer and planting density produces the greatest crop yield in a field experiment. We assign different plots in a field to a combination of fertilizer type (1, 2, or 3) and planting density (1=low density, 2=high density), and measure the final crop yield in bushels per acre at harvest time.

So, how can we test the 2 null hypotheses simultaneously while controlling the family wise error-rate at alpha = 0.05:

H01: There is no difference between the effects of the fertilizer type on the amount of harvest.

H02: There is no difference between the effects of the planting density on the amount of harvest.

I know how we can do this type of test in one way anova, but I am confused for the two-way case.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution is to use Bonferroni here. Just require .025 thresholds for the p-values. Because of the 2 way structure, your test statistics should not be highly correlated, so Bonferroni will not lose much power relative to the more powerful (but harder to implement) solution that utilizes correlation structure.

Comment: I don't see why hypothesis testing is relevant here (as opposed to estimation).  I suggest computing simultaneous 0.95 compatibility (aka confidence) intervals for all contrasts of interest.  Simultaneous confidence intervals are a more statistically unique way to control for multiplicity (as opposed to the arbitrary choice of p-value adjustments).

Comment: Except one of the hypotheses involved multiple parameters. I agree, Frank, but I was just answering the question that was asked. If you want to get CIs for all the parameters, there will be four inferences rather than two, and the correlation issue will be more substantial. There are examples in my various books showing how to utilize such correlations to get the right intervals for these four parameters.

Comment: There is a general approach to this that doesn't require explicit estimation of those correlations.  For linear models and approximately for GLMs in general the R `rms` package `contrast` function with `type='simultaneous'` makes this painless.

Comment: No need to estimate the correlations as they are known exactly here (or more precisely, the dependence structure is known). And if you don't use that information, the inferences will not achieve the nominal FWER for the simultaneous intervals.